# Injecting javascript before PartialViewResult script is executed in EXT.NET?

Tags: javascript, code-injection, ext.net

I have a partial view which is requested & loaded into a modal window.

Following is the action method which generates the partial view:

```
public Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult GetPartialView()
{
    var p = new Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult { Model = ...., ViewName = "MyPartialView" };
    //!!need to manipulate p here to run my custom javascript on client!!
    return p;
}
```

After GetPartialView() is called via ajax request, necessary scripts are generated and sent back to the client.

The executing script looks like this:

```
{script:"Ext.net.ResourceMgr.registerIcon([\"TextListBullets\",\"Add\"]);Ext.onReady(function(){Ext.create(\"Ext.window.Window\",{height:400,hidden..... bla bla}
```

**Question:**

How can i inject my own custom code somewhere in this generated javascript block?

**My purpose** is to dynamically load some external javascript files which are needed in the partial view.

I dont want to statically include script references in every main view i use this partial view. I want to gain some kind of automatization by loading js files when they are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sharing the answer from Ext.NET forum:

Please see the following sample
http://mvc.ext.net/#/Dynamic_Partial_Rendering/Add_Tab/

```
@{    MvcResourceManager.RegisterGlobalStyle(Url.Content("~/Areas/Dynamic_Partial_Rendering/Content/Tab.css"));}
```